# Mock private method used in the constructor Mockito

Tags: methods, constructor, private

I'm trying to test the method in the class, which has constructor as follows:

```
public class ResponseReader {

public ResponseReader(Socket client){
        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(createFile()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not initiate ResponseReader");
        }
    }
```

"createFile" method in the constructor is private:

```
private static File createFile() {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddhhmmss");
        String dateAsString = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
        File uartDataFile = new File("/root/Logs/" + dateAsString + "data.log");
        LOG.debug("Created data file {}", dataFile);
        return dataFile;
    }
```

When I am trying to test method from this class I need to create new object and thus need to mock constructor instances before I create mock of the class:

```
  private Socket client;
    private InputStreamReader inputStreamReaderMock;
    private InputStream inputStreamMock;
    private BufferedReader bufferedReaderMock;
    private ResponseReader responseReaderMock;

@BeforeEach
public void init() throws Exception {
        inputStreamReaderMock = mock(InputStreamReader.class);
        bufferedReaderMock = mock(BufferedReader.class);
        inputStreamMock = mock(InputStream.class);
        client = mock(Socket.class);
        when(client.getInputStream()).thenReturn(inputStreamMock);

        responseReaderMock = Mockito.spy(new ResponseReader(client));
        PowerMockito.whenNew(BufferedReader.class).
                withArguments(inputStreamReaderMock).
                thenReturn(bufferedReaderMock);
}
```

It works till "new FileWriter(createFile()))".
Could someone advise how to mock private method which is used in the constructor? So I need to mock this method before I am mocking class.

Comment: You can indicate that you expect a private call to be made by using the PowerMockito function expectPrivate. In your case, you could do something like `expectPrivate(responseReaderMock, createFile).andReturn(fileMock)`, where `fileMock = mock(File.class)`.

Comment: From the way you are using createFile(), I'm going to assume that it is not a static method. PowerMockito is handy when you need to mock a method of a class before creating the actual class. You have to suppress createFile(), create the ResponseReader mock object, and then stub createFile().

Comment: @anusha could you please give me an example how it should look like? As I tried already many different options and all failed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by adding setters and empty constructor in my ResponseReader class:

```
  public ResponseReader(){}

    //this is used only for testing purpose
    public void setBufferedReader(BufferedReader bufferedReader) {
        this.bufferedReader = bufferedReader;
    }

    //this is used only for testing purpose
    public void setBufferedWriter(BufferedWriter bufferedWriter) {
        this.bufferedWriter = bufferedWriter;
    }
```

and then in the tests:

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(BufferedWriter.class).withArguments(fileWriterMock).thenReturn(bufferedWriterMock);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(BufferedReader.class).
                withArguments(inputStreamReaderMock).
                thenReturn(bufferedReaderMock);
        responseReaderMock.setBufferedReader(bufferedReaderMock);
        responseReaderMock.setBufferedWriter(bufferedWriterMock);
```